# Return duplicate min values

Tags: oracle

See the table below for reference. I need to return duplicate rows containing the min value.

In this example I want to show only the 2 rows that have SLAT_LEN = 30 or rather the min SLAT_LEN. I tried rank but when I do it does a consecutive rank.  I want the duplicate sizes to have the same rank and to rank consecutively by size.

The sizes change so I can't just use a condition like SLAT_LEN = 30.

Or is there a different approach that I should take?

```
   select *
   from(
    select lg.wd_demand_id,wm.slat_len, wm.prof_size, wm.wd_material_id, wm.color, rank() over ( partition by wm.slat_len order by lg.wd_demand_id) as rank
    from wd_demand_log lg, wd_bins wb, wd_material wm, wd_bins_material wbm
    where lg.wd_bins_id = wb.wd_bins_id
    and lg.wd_material_id = wm.wd_material_id
    and lg.wd_bins_id = wbm.wd_bins_id
    and lg.wd_material_id = wbm.wd_material_id
    AND lg.plant_id = 44 AND lg.dept_id = 220 AND wb.plant_id = 44 AND wb.dept_id = 220
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT dmpln.wd_demand_id  FROM wd_demnd_pln_inv dmpln WHERE dmpln.wd_demand_id = lg.wd_demand_id)
    AND wm.prof_size = '2' AND wm.color = 450
    AND lg.wd_po_error is null)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get that rank thing. Why `partition by wm.slat_len`? Why `order by lg.wd_demand_id`? Aren't you simply looking for `rank() over (order by wm.slat_len)`? (Or rather `ORDER BY wm.slat_len FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES` in case you have Oracle 12c?)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks!  I didn't even consider removing "partition by".  That gave me exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Okay, I'll post this as an answer, so future readers find the solution easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `PARTITION BY` to give the range in which to rank. The `ORDER BY` specifies the ranking. So in your case you'll need something like

```
rank() over (order by wm.slat_len)
```

In case you have Oracle 12c you can limit your results with `FETCH FIRST`:

```
ORDER BY wm.slat_len 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am not understanding the problem correctly, but here is my potential solution:

```
WITH aset
     AS (SELECT lg.wd_demand_id
              , wm.slat_len
              , wm.prof_size
              , wm.wd_material_id
              , wm.color
           FROM wd_demand_log lg, wd_bins wb, wd_material wm
              , wd_bins_material wbm
          WHERE lg.wd_bins_id = wb.wd_bins_id
            AND lg.wd_material_id = wm.wd_material_id
            AND lg.wd_bins_id = wbm.wd_bins_id
            AND lg.wd_material_id = wbm.wd_material_id
            AND lg.plant_id = 44
            AND lg.dept_id = 220
            AND wb.plant_id = 44
            AND wb.dept_id = 220
            AND NOT EXISTS
                    (SELECT dmpln.wd_demand_id
                       FROM wd_demnd_pln_inv dmpln
                      WHERE dmpln.wd_demand_id = lg.wd_demand_id)
            AND wm.prof_size = '2'
            AND wm.color = 450
            AND lg.wd_po_error IS NULL)
SELECT *
  FROM aset
 WHERE slat_len = (SELECT MIN (slat_len)
                     FROM aset)
```